Thanking admin/HR for deadline exceptions
I just finished grad school at a large public university, although this question is more about workplace etiquette than anything specific to academia. Due to a combination of poor planning and external events beyond my control, I missed (by 2-3 days) some important deadlines required to graduate in the semester I intended to - which would have both caused me major problems professionally and annoyed people who made the trip for my commencement. I emailed the assistant dean to ask if I could graduate on time despite missing the deadlines for no real reason, and to my surprise they made all the exceptions necessary for me to graduate. They also strongly implied in their response email that this caused them a nontrivial amount of extra work at a time when I assume they are already very busy.
Now that I'm "done", would it be appropriate to send them an email just to thank them for doing whatever was necessary to process me after the graduation deadline? On one hand, I want to express my appreciation that they went above and beyond in a scenario where it would have been completely reasonable to ignore or explicitly reject me. On the other hand, I would hate to contribute to inbox clutter or be (more of) a nuisance by sending a "thank you" email that doesn't require a response.

would it be appropriate to send them an email just to thank them for doing whatever was necessary to process me after the graduation deadline? - Yes.

I think you could probably go ahead and send it now. You could also wait a week or two to let things (hopefully) die down on their end, so they receive it at a less stressful time.

If you can afford it, send an actual sharable gift, such as a fruit basket, or chocolates. Or stop by with such a thing (or some home made cookies) to say thankyou in person. Let them know it mattered to you.

Agree on the shareable gift. Depending on the mindset, unfortunately homemade or an unsealed edible gift might be look upon with apprehension. Go with store bought and sealed to be safe.

People like statements of appreciation, so that won't be a nuisance.  Send the email thanking them and highlighting the time they took at a busy period.  However, all that said, I recommend sending a handwritten note (too or instead) plus a jug of coffee or tea if you can.
